How to deal with unmovable files like MFT when trying to shrink a partition?
I want to add more space to my Linux OS partition, but can't because of unmovable files on C:; I've tried several ways, yet am still unable to, including disabling paging files, system protection, kernel memory dumps, and hibernation mode.

After looking for alternative solutions, I found the unmovable files are \$Mft::$DATA:   

Is it dangerous to tamper with these files, and if not, how can I solve the problem I'm facing?

Beyond defragging, never touch the $Mft [Master File Table]

Thank you @joepvansteen for your attention. I didn't realize anyone had an identical problem before.
I'm interested in your answer in the link you provided. But I don't really understand the solution flow by using defraggler. Can I get an explanation of how to use it?


is it dangerous to tamper with these files?

The $Mft file is probably the most dangerous of them, as it holds the information about files themselves – which is also why it's not movable while the volume is in use.

If not, how can I solve the problem I'm facing?

Do the resize from a different Windows system – e.g. from an installation USB stick – so that the partition will not be "in use" (as the system partition) during the resize. The resizing tool will then be able to dismount it and move all files (including the MFT, the pagefile, the hiberfile, etc.) because they're no longer in use by the system at that moment.
